# Is it possible to sort Kubernetes API list of ConfigMaps?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is it possible to sort Kubernetes API list of ConfigMaps?

Say you have an endpoint `https://<DOMAIN>:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps`, and you are fetching the list of config maps. Is there any way to send a GET request with sorting params in the query?

For ex: `https://<DOMAIN>:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/configmaps?sort=name:DESC` (which did not work)

Comment: You can combine this with jq: `/api/v1/namespaces/defaultconfigmaps | jq -rM '.items[].metadata.name`

Answer (score 2):

As I know, you need to sort it by yourself.
[k8s-api-cm-refer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#-strong-read-operations-strong--198) hasn't sort parameters.